# Solve the equation $y''\sin t-2y'\cos t-y\sin t=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, trigonometry

Solve the differential equation $y''\sin t -2y'\cos t-y\sin t=0$

My try:

I assumed $z=y \sin t$

Then we have:

$$z'=y\cos t+y'\sin t$$

$$z''=-y\sin t+2y'\cos t+y''\sin t$$

Is there a way out here?

Comment: Try $z=\frac y{\sin t}$ to get the correct sign combination in the derivatives.

Comment: You can guess that one solution is $y=\cos t$. Then use reduction of order to find the other one

Answer (score 2):

Make the following substitutions:
$$y(t)=v(t)cos(t)$$ then we get
$$\cos(t)v''(t)\sin(t)-2v'(t)=0$$
now let $$v'(t)=u(t)$$ and we get
$$\int\frac{\frac{du(t)}{dt}}{u(t)}dt=\int2\csc(t)\sec(t)dt$$
I hope you can finish!

Comment: Very nice i am getting: $v'(t)=\tan^2 t$ $\implies$ $v=\tan t-t+C$ So $y=\sin t-t\cos t+C \cos t$, but answer is given $y=\cos t$

Comment: @Umeshshankar : The given basis solution $y_1=\cos t$ allows to find the second basis solution as $y=v\cos t$ as carried out in this answer. You get the first basis solution back in the term $C\cos t$ (note that in-between you have set an integration constant to $0$). Setting $C=0$ you find the second basis solution as $y_2?\sin t-t\cos t$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Alternativelly to LutzL's proposal, you can also use the "simpler"

$$y = v(t)\sin(t) \implies \frac{\mathrm{d}y(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} =\cos(t)\frac{\mathrm{d}v(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}-\sin(t)v(t)$$